# Do python have namespace functionality?

Tags: python, programming-languages

I have heard a lot about namespace as a feature for programming language. Thus, can not help thinking:

Does Python have so called namespace feature?

Comment: Hint: try `import this` from the Python shell to see exactly what Python thinks about namespaces.

Comment: I get ~885,000 hits in Google for *"python namespace"*, have you considered reading any of those?

Answer (score 2):

Quote from Python documentation:

A namespace is a mapping from names to objects. Most namespaces are currently implemented as Python dictionaries, but that’s normally not noticeable in any way (except for performance), and it may change in the future. Examples of namespaces are: the set of built-in names (containing functions such as abs(), and built-in exception names); the global names in a module; and the local names in a function invocation. In a sense the set of attributes of an object also form a namespace. The important thing to know about namespaces is that there is absolutely no relation between names in different namespaces; for instance, two different modules may both define a function maximize without confusion — users of the modules must prefix it with the module name.

Answer (score 0):

For a good overview, see the "Python Scopes and Namespaces" section of the Python tutorial at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces.